# Mocha throws "Resolution method is overspecified"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm trying to write a simple test -

```
describe("My test", function(){
  it("Succeed", function*(done){
    yield testFunc();
    done()
  })
})

function *testFunc(){
  console.log("Hey!")
}
```

Note that I'm using co-mocha so that my generator will be executed.

The error that I get is -

```
Error: Resolution method is overspecified. Specify a callback *or* return a Promise; not both.
```

Now, the docs clearly state -

> when a test injects a callback function (suggesting asynchronous execution), calls it, and returns a Promise, Mocha will now throw an exception

https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#boom-breaking-changes

However, **I'm not returning a Promise!** I'm injecting the `done` function which is a callback, but I'm not returning a Promise... yielding testFunc doesn't return a Promise.

So, why is this test throwing an error?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The generator (`function*`) or rather it's coroutine-creating wrapper that's implicit here is most likely returning a promise. I'm not exactly sure how the `co-mocha` works here but maybe this would work:

```
describe("My test", function () {
  it("Succeed", function* () {
    yield testFunc();
    return;
  });
});
```

The return is not needed here, just added for clarity.

But you may need to change:

```
function *testFunc(){
  console.log("Hey!")
}
```

to something like:

```
let testFunc = co.wrap(function* () {
  console.log("Hey!");
});
```

for your `yield` in the code above to work.

If you're using `co` coroutines then your generators should yield promises. Here, you're generator yields the result of running a generator function that itself returns a generator, not a promise.

Answer (score 2):

Your assumption that no promise is used is incorrect. `co-mocha` uses `co.wrap`  [internally](https://github.com/blakeembrey/co-mocha/blob/82b06fce198dbb43b089e7b88fdbe15265c3a33c/co-mocha.js#L34) to wrap the functions you pass to `it`. The documentation for [`co.wrap`](https://github.com/tj/co#var-fn--cowrapfn) says:

> Convert a generator into a regular function **that returns a Promise.**

Emphasis added.

Answer (score 1):

Removing done as a param worked for me! Example is as follows:

BEFORE:

```
it('receives successful response', async (done) => { 
const getSomeData = await getResponse(unitData, function callBack(unit, error, data){ 
    expect(data.statusCode).to.be.equal(200); 
    done(); 
}) })
```

AFTER (works):

```
it('receives successful response', async () => { 
const getSomeData = await getResponse(unitData, function callBack(unit, error, data){
     expect(data.statusCode).to.be.equal(200); 
}) })
```

Comment: I have a similar issue but the problem when using your solution is that the test doesn't fail if you change 200 to 2. are you seeing a similar behavior?